# How to executing arbitrary sql from pyspark notebook using SQLContext?

Tags: ibm-cloud, apache-spark-sql, pyspark, jupyter, dashdb

I'm trying a basic test case of reading data from dashDB into spark and then writing it back to dashDB again.

*Step 1*. First within the notebook, I read the data:

```
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
dashdata = sqlContext.read.jdbc(
     url="jdbc:db2://bluemix05.bluforcloud.com:50000/BLUDB:user=****;password=****;",  
     table="GOSALES.BRANCH"
).cache()
```

*Step 2*. Then from dashDB I create the target table:

```
DROP TABLE ****.FROM_SPARK;
CREATE TABLE ****.FROM_SPARK AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM GOSALES.BRANCH
) WITH NO DATA
```

*Step 3*. Finally, within the notebook I save the data to the table:

```
from pyspark.sql import DataFrameWriter
writer = DataFrameWriter(dashdata)
dashdata = writer.jdbc(
    url="jdbc:db2://bluemix05.bluforcloud.com:50000/BLUDB:user=****;password=****;",  
    table="****.FROM_SPARK"
)
```

**Question**: Is it possible to run the sql in step 2 from pyspark?  I couldn't see how this could be done from the [pyspark documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#).  I don't want to use [vanilla python](https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb) for connecting to dashDB because of the effort involved in setting up the library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [ibmdbpy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ibmdbpy). See this brief [demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tk9T1yPkn4c).

With as_idadataframe() you can upload DataFrames into dashDB as a table.

---

**Added key steps here as stackoverflow doesn't like linking to answers:**

*Step 1:* Add a cell containing:

```
#!pip install --user future
#!pip install --user lazy
#!pip install --user jaydebeapi
#!pip uninstall --yes ibmdbpy
#!pip install ibmdbpy --user --no-deps
#!wget -O $HOME/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ibmdbpy/db2jcc4.jar https://ibm.box.com/shared/static/lmhzyeslp1rqns04ue8dnhz2x7fb6nkc.zip
```

*Step 2:* Then from annother notebook cell

```
from ibmdbpy import IdaDataBase
idadb = IdaDataBase('jdbc:db2://<dashdb server name>:50000/BLUDB:user=<dashdb user>;password=<dashdb pw>') 
....
```

Comment: Presumably you have uploaded db2jcc4.jar to your box account?  IBM should make these files available on the internet as relying on downloading file from informal sources is a security risk and unreliable as files tend to disappear over time.

Comment: Yes, this is just a temporary fix for getting the driver to be picked up in this Bluemix Notebook env. We are working on a proper solution.

Comment: Ah, great!  Is there a ticket for the proper solution that I can subscribe to?

Comment: has the jar file been uploaded to an official repo?

Answer (score 0):

```
Yes,
You can create table in dashdb from Notebook.
Below is the code for Scala :

import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import org.apache.log4j.Level
import java.sql.Connection
import java.sql.DriverManager
import java.sql.SQLException
import com.ibm.db2.jcc._

import java.io._

    val jdbcClassName="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver"
    val url="jdbc:db2://awh-yp-small02.services.dal.bluemix.net:50001/BLUDB:sslConnection=true;" // enter the hostip fromc connection settings
    val user="<username>" 
    val password="<password>" 
    Class.forName(jdbcClassName)
    val connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password)
    val stmt = connection.createStatement()

stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE COL12345(" +



                     "month VARCHAR(82))")

    stmt.close()
        connection.commit()
      connection.close()
```